# Hiearchical Clustering in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I want to perform a Hiearchical Clustering in R but I'm facing some problems handling the results. I'm using `agnes` function, which gives me a dendogram and the agglomerative coefficient and so on. Now, how can I find which are the most significant Clusters? How can I get the observations that are Clustered in the Cluster number X, for instance? I want to get the points inside each cluster.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used hierarchical clustering. What you get back is a hierarchy, not a clustering.  If you want to see clusters, you have to decide how many clusters  or equivalently,  where you want to cut the tree. You can then use `cutree` to group the observations into clusters.  Here is a quick example. Since you do not provide any data, I will use the built-in iris data as an example.

```
library(cluster)
AG = agnes(iris[,1:4])

## use the hierarchy to make 3 clusters
cutree(AG, 3)

  [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [38] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 [75] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3
[112] 3 3 2 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 3 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 2 3
[149] 3 2
```